# Azure switch application gateway by frontdoor because bandwidth is not enough is a good idea?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

We have deployed our website recently using an application gateway but the bandwidth (125 CU) isn't enough to handle the very high traffic of the website.

We are thinking about switching the application gateway by a Frontdoor since it looks like its bandwidth is higher however we don’t know if there are anything we should know by using this method. (security, best pratice, cost, ...)

Our website is host in 2 same App service Plan (with 4 to 5 App Service in each of theme) in the same region.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you guys use actual firewall (not Azure WAF, rather something like PaloAlto, Fortigate, Cisco FTD etc) for this. Not only it will work as application gateway but will also provide you security and save you from a lot of attacks. It is fairly simple to deploy a firewall from market place, and vendor support is also great. Depending on how good you negotiate the price difference will be marginal.

Comment: I'm confused, how a firewall will solve our bandwidth issue.

Comment: Because bandwidth restrictions apply to application gateway in azure depending on how you build it, which doesn't in case of Firewall,  only restriction you have is the Size of VM (as NIC is associated to it). So for very high traffic websites, I'll move on to CDN service. Other way would be using firewall along with ILB for application servers. There are way too may possabilities, and if you are looking for quick solution, have you tried to increase throughput of application gateway to see if that helps ?